# como cambio el valor de un radio button con AngularJS?

Tags: html5, angularjs

mi problema es el siguiente:
tengo dos radios definidos de la siguiente manera :

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label>
     <input type="radio" name="internacional" ng-model="internacional" id="RadioSi" ng-value="true"  />
     SI
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label>
     <input type="radio" name="internacional" ng-model="internacional" id="RadioNo" ng-value="false" />
     NO
  </label>
```

para tomar sus datos no tengo problema, el problema es cuando lo intento cambiar desde el controlador, supongamos que con el metodo get traigo un objeto y uso uno de sus campos que son true o false desde BD y lo quiero remplazar en el form.
yo uso:

```
 $scope.internacional = aer.internacional;
```

pero el boton no cambia de si a o no como corresponderia. uso angularjs

Answer (score 3):

Cuando tienes 2 o mas radio con el mismo nombre, solo 1 puede estar seleccionado:

```html
<input type="radio" name="ch" />
<input type="radio" name="ch" >
```

Intenta negar el valor del `ng-value` en uno de los `radio` para cuando uno este checked y otro no lo este:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope, $http){
  $scope.model = {value: true};
  $scope.val = true;
  $scope.model.modificar = function() {
    $scope.model.value = !$scope.model.value;
  };
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="radio" name="ch1" ng-model="val" ng-value="model.value" /> 
<input type="radio" name="ch1" ng-model="val" ng-value="!model.value" /> 
<button ng-click="model.modificar()">Modificar</button>
</div>
```